# Установка нового соеденеия при обрыве старого

Tags: python, requests

**Код:**

```
for i in range(50):
    r = requests.get("http://synapsenet.ru", headers=headers_data, proxies=proxies)
```

Код максимально упрощён для удобства решения проблемы

**Проблема:** После определённой итерации возникает ошибка  соединения (соединение не совсем стабильное из-за proxy )

**Задача:** При возникновении этой ошибки скрипт должен пытаться   установить новое соединение до тех пор пока не получит код ответа 200 ok

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Comment: как доки о сокетах должны мне помочь?

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? `repeat r = requests.get(..,) until r.result_code = 200` тоже самое только на питоне...

Comment: мне нужно что бы при возникновении ошибки с соединением скрипт пытался установить соединение заново до тех пор пока он не получить 200ok

Comment: Ну так проблема в чем? вы незнаете как организовать цикл? Вы не знаете как проверить какой код ответа пришел? вы не понимаете как организовать повтор? повтор циклом, остальное - в доках

Comment: после определённой итерации скрипт выбрасывает ошибку соединения и останавливается

Comment: Как мне сделать так что бы после возникновения ошибки он не останавливался а пытался установить новое соединение?

Comment: Обрабатывать ошибки `try Действие except Действие при ошибке`

Comment: попробовал сделать так:

Comment: for i in range(50):
 try:
  r = requests.get("http://synapsenet.ru", headers=headers_data, proxies=proxies)
 except Exception:
  while True:
   r = requests.get("http://synapsenet.ru", headers=headers_data, proxies=proxies)
   if r.status_code == 200:
    break

Comment: но внутри while возникает ошибка из-за чего скрипт останавливается

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://synapsenet.ru", headers=headers_data, proxies=proxies)
        break
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score -1):

Питона не знаю, зато гугл сразу рассказал:

```
try:
    a = float(input("Введите число: ")
    print (100 / a)
except ValueError:
    print ("Это не число!")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ("На ноль делить нельзя!")
except:
    print ("Неожиданная ошибка.")
else:
    print ("Код выполнился без ошибок")
finally:
    print ("Я выполняюсь в любом случае!")
```

Вот такой нехитрой комбинацией можно обрабатывать любые ошибки, реагировать на них и продолжать выполнение если это необходимо.

```
for i in range(50): 
  REPEAT
    try: 
      r = requests.get("synapsenet.ru", headers=headers_data, proxies=proxies) 
    except:
      print ("Неожиданная ошибка.")
  UNTIL r.status_code == 200
```

Comment: внутри except я могу сделать ещё одно соединение, но не факт что оно будет удачным

Comment: Зачем? смотрите внимательно границы цикла =)

Comment: оно будет удачным через n количества попыток

Comment: @evseygames Смотрите пример, оно будет повторятся пока не будет удачным... =)

Comment: NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Comment: в блоке  с except

Comment: @evseygames логично, вы же `r` не не описали, я его тоже не описывал =) Я питон не знаю от слова совсем, и не знаю какой тип должен быть у `r`, вы эту часть кода опустили, и как она выглядеть должна - мне не известно =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86212/discussion-between-evseygames-and--).

Comment: в любом случаи, при возникновении ошибки он просто будет писать "Неожиданная ошибка."  и просто идти к следующей итерации, он не будет пытаться установить новое соединение